# C# - UnitTest message received through IBM Websphere MQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ibm-mq

I am new to IBM Websphere MQ.

In our projet, I have implemented code to read messages from IBM MQ.

I have installed IBM WebSphere client and I am using references of **IBM.XMS** and **IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ** to create the connection and read the message from the queue.

```
XMSFactoryFactory xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
IConnectionFactory cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
```

I have set the necessary properties like HostName, Channel, Port, QueueManager.

I have created the MessageListener:

```
MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener(Method to process the message);
```

I have assigned listener to consumer:

```
consumer.MessageListener = messageListener;
```

I am able to connect to queue manager, read the message and display that message in WPF window.

Now for above code I have to write the UnitTest.

As per my knowledge, in unittest we won't be creating connection and reading from queue so how can I mock above code so that I can pass dummy message and check that.

Comment: Abstract the dependencies behind an interface to make them mockable. that way your can swap them out for mocks when testing.

Comment: Show a definition of the listener and an example of how the listener is consumed. From that the required/expected functionality can be ascertained and an abstraction can be created.

Answer (score 0):

The XMS API you are calling will actually communicate with a queue manager. So without a queue manager the API's will fail and so will the unit test.